# PHP XML removing elements

Tags: php, xml

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<images>
    <pic>
        <image>54</image>
        <descr>Image 1</descr>
    </pic>
    <pic>
        <image>32</image>
        <descr>Image 2</descr>
    </pic>
    <pic>
        <image>47</image>
        <descr>Image 3</descr>
    </pic>
</images>
```

I want to remove one element, for example second pic (image 32). Using this code, but it's not working.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('../../images.xml');

$target = false;
$i = 0;
foreach ($xml->pic as $m) {
  if ($m['image']=='32') { $target = $i; break; }
  $i++;
}
if ($target !== false) {      //$target always be $false
  unset($xml->pic[$target]);
}

echo $xml->savexml();
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observations

`$m` is object not array so `$m['image']` should be changed to `$m->image`

Change `$target = false;` to `$target = 0 ;`

Example

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file ( '1.xml' );
$target = 0;
$i = 0;
foreach ( $xml->pic as $m ) {
    if ($m->image == '32') {
        $target = $i;
        break;
    }
    $i ++;
}

if ($target !== false) {
    unset ( $xml->pic [$target] );
}
echo $xml->savexml ();
```

Comment: This will not work.  His original test for target was fine - this code will always delete the 2nd `pic`.

Comment: +1 thanks @Sam Dufel .. just notice the dependency on `$i` change my script

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new `XML` object, and add only the data you want and save the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is wrong

```
if ($target !== false) {
```

should be

```
if ($target > 0) {
```

Comment: !== tests for same value AND type. 0 is never !== false (boolean and int).

Comment: Reread his code.  He's initializing target to `false`, and setting it to an integer value when he finds the correct index.  If `target === false`, the correct index was never found.  Otherwise, target has been set to the index of the element he's deleting (and 0 is a valid index).